# Is AngularFire $bindTo a valid substitute for transactions?

Tags: angularjs, transactions, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to track a few counters in firebase, such as the numbers of views of a video.

Firebase recommends using [transactions](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/transaction.html)for doing so, but after reading about AngularFire's three way data binding, I was wondering if same feat could be achieved via the $bindTo.

Comment: Nope, they're unrelated. Objects bound with `$bindTo` use regular `set`/`update` operations behind the scenes.

Comment: ok, thanks for the prompt reply.